# HP dv5 1199el - How to burn recovery disks without HP recovery Manager

Tags: windows

I unfortunatly removed the HP recovery Manager on my HP dv5 1199el, and I'd like to burn the recovery disks right now, but i can't find that software!

OS : Windows Vista Home Premium 32bit

Someone can help me?

Cheers

EDIT :
i've found it on the HP webiste, and is called sp41949.exe
I've take a look into SwSetup from my Hard Disk, and i have that package :) Unfortunatly, when i start it, i get an error : *The installer can not be installed on this system, Installation with abort!*
Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search your hard drive for CDCreator.exe, this is the program that makes the discs.

Which OS do you have?
.

If all else fails you can order them for a small fee from HP.

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00810334&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

.

EDIT:

As a last resort you can back up your personal data to an external drive and then attempt a HP recovery from the partition, you do this by tapping F11 at the HP logo screen at the start of the boot process, hopefully this will load HP recovery, it will restore the OS and all original software, then you should be able to create the discs, this process will wipe all your personal data so back up!

Scroll down to "Restore the PC to its original condition with the HP recovery manager if Windows Vista is not available"

This process can take many hours, be patient and do not cancel the process once it starts.

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00809678&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

.

Comment: I have Windows Vista Home Premium 32 bit. Yes i could order them, but i won't pay €38,40 :( I don't have CDCreator.exe. There aren't any way to create DVD from my partition without that software???

Comment: Not that I have ever found. :-(, I did an edit of my post, please read.

Comment: Yes, i get this suggestion many time, but I hoped in another way :)